# Alt-tab (suddenly?) disabled in root account on Gnome Classic (with/without Effects)

Tags: gnome, root

It appears that alt-tab does not work correctly in atleast Gnome Classic and Gnome Classic without Effects in the root account.

In Gnome Classic, Alt-Tab does not initate any execution. The alt key underlines the menu items in a window and the tab key fails to do anything.

In Gnome Classic without Effects, Alt-Tab does not function correctly. It brings up the standard Alt-Tab switcher Window (not the ccsm one) but the window does not contain all of the windows opened on the desktop. Instead it contains just the window with the highest z-order. When executing alt-tab on the desktop, instead of a greyed out panel, the panel is filled with the desktop itself. In some instances the panel is filled with the highest z-order window and the desktop. Either way, the functionality is clearly malfunctioning.

I do not wish to use the ccsm application switcher. I wish to use the standard application switcher (the one that is similar to the windows application switcher).

There is no effect to enabling the keybinding of "Switch Application" in gconf-editor along the metacity package.

Please do not discuss the suitability or recommendations regarding running root.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this has something to do with the Gnome Classic with Effects WM. Executing `metacity --replace` reset the WM to a Gnome Classic without Effects version and facilitates this functionality.